# 09 civic immobilizer problems

Tags: honda, ignition

I went to Jail for 5 days and while I was in there some idiots tried to steal my 2009 Honda Civic sedan. They tore the ignition apart totally destroyed everything including the immobilizer I replaced the whole ignition and immobilizer and now car will start for only a second then shut off, and green light flashes. I purchased a key reprogramer but says it can't link up to my ecu. What do I do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm pretty sure you're either going to need to get a locksmith who deals with this, or take it to the dealership.